# How to equally space out divs after certain elements have a set width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I must create table without using `<table>`; only `<div>`. How I can set width (in percent) on some blocks so that others divide the rest of the space equally.

I can do it with JS but I think its possible with html/css only.

Comment: You can use flexbox to define some child elements with set widths and leave the rest for the browser to space out evenly.

This resource may help: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox it's rather easy to create a table like structure. Specify a flex basis for the table cells (boxes) + a grow and shrink to make them resize properly.

Check this fiddle with the demo :)

https://jsfiddle.net/xs0pmgbL/

HTML code:

```
  <div id="container">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS code:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: orange;
    flex: 1 1 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```